# How to get C# If Else Logic To Exclude Members of an AD Security Group?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following code to get the AD security groups of the current user.

```
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name).GetAuthorizationGroups();

        IEnumerable<string> groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.Name);
```

I have checked, and all of the user's security groups are contained in groupNames.  However, the following logic isn't working properly - it blocks the "Admins" and "Mgrs" as well as everybody else:

```
if (!(groupNames.Contains("Admins") || groupNames.Contains("Mgrs"))) { Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx"); }
```

I have also tried the following, and it doesn't work either - instead it lets everybody view the page:

```
if (groupNames.Contains("Admins") || groupNames.Contains("Mgrs"))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
        }
```

Is my syntax or logic incorrect?  I need all users in the "Admins" or "Mgrs" security groups to be able to access the page, and all other users shouldbe redirected to AccessDenied.aspx.

This is an asp.net webforms application using visual studio 2019.

Comment: The syntax and boolean logic seems correct. Have you used the debugger to confirm that `groupNames` really contains what you think it contains?

Comment: How about searching for "Administrators" instead of "Admins". Try to look for the exact string you are searching for. Oh and beware of language specifications. In a German environment you would get "Administratoren" instead of "Administrators"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but it's working now.  I'm using the same code, no changes...

```
if (groupNames.Contains("Admins") || groupNames.Contains("Mgrs"))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
    }
```